# Ogre Application without any mesh gives about 60 fps.

Tags: opengl, rendering, ogre

I have made a very basic ogre application which doesn't load any mesh. It just output render window. The fps count is about 60 which I think is very low. Is it possible to increase the fps count?
My settings are:
Render System=OpenGL Rendering Subsystem
[OpenGL Rendering Subsystem]
Display Frequency=60 Hz
FSAA=0
Fixed Pipeline Enabled=Yes
Full Screen=No 
RTT Preferred Mode=FBO
VSync=No
Video Mode=1280 x 800
sRGB Gamma Conversion=No
CPU: core 2 duo 2.1 GHz
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vsync will lock your framerate to the display rate, tipically 60 Hz (or a multiple like 30 or 15 Hz), so disabling Vsync will "solve your problem".

Comment: Thanks Matias, but the Vsync is already disabled as given in the settings. Also to further check, I have hard-coded to disable the vsync, but it doesn't help.

Comment: It is the only reasonable explanation for it to be stuck at 60 fps. Even your display frequency is 60. Your driver is probably just overriding your application's settings. Try fiddling with your drivers instead.

Comment: Thanks Matias, Invalid. setting environment variable vblank_mode=1 does the trick. Now I am getting fps of around 1200.